# JavaScript for disabling Tab Key to go to browser tab and address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once I have an JS alert active, I am trying to stop tab key from going to browser bar and address in Firefox. I have the form focus working just cannot work out how to stop tabbing to the browser level once a JS alert is fired. Any idea how I can fix that?
My code:

```
$('a').on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
    if( e.which == 9 ) {
        console.log( 'pressed');
    }
} );
```

Comment: Why would you want this? If the user wants to go to the address bar, it's up to them. Trying to change the default behavior of the browser is considered a big no-no. Also, the code you posted doesn't have anything to do with any alert. It checks for a keypress on all achor tags on the page.

Comment: it is specific of impaired users so it is needed to be done that way

Comment: its possible to create windows with a deactivated address bar but what you are searching for seems hard to achieve without any browser plugins. Note also that those "keyboard event numbers" like your `9` will be deprecated in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the keydown event, and prevent default actions then return false:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: But that will disable the tab key

Comment: @SMH - If you add the event listener before the alert and then remove it after the alert is closed. Then it will only be disabled while the alert is open.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking to create a scenario that you are explaining. I created an alert box and then print to the console the name of the active element. The problem is that when the alert box is active the browser halts JavaScript. It is not possible with an alert box.

```
function javaScriptIsRunning(){
  console.log("running");
  setTimeout(javaScriptIsRunning, 1000);
};

javaScriptIsRunning();

alert('a');
var onKeyUpcode = document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  console.log(document.activeElement.localName);

});
```